# Getting the pressed character without using edidtext

Tags: android

1. I want to get a pressed character in the code without using `edittext`.

   Simply a black screen appear if someone presses "a" or "b" etc.. I want to get this value in my code.

   I have done it using editext and textwatcher but the requirement is we don't need to use them now.
2. Can we make character(alphabet) moving from top to bottom randomly

   I have followed some links which have used `marquee` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

In your Activity override the method

```
 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
      if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_A) {
          //Here your black screen if you press A
              return true;

         }
          return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
        }
```

Check this [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) ;